# Why is my xdebug.remote_host different from the value declared in php.ini?

Tags: php, xdebug

I am running `php-fpm` in a Docker container. In my `php.ini` file, I have `xdebug.remote_host=10.100.9.87`.

When I run `php -i|grep remote_host`, I get `xdebug.remote_host => 10.100.9.87 => 10.100.9.87`

I can run `php test.php` from the CLI and it will trigger the debugger in my IDE.

However, when I create a file with `phpinfo()` and execute it through `nginx`, the value of `remote_host` is listed as `192.168.0.16` for both local and master value. There is no machine at that IP, and I don't know where that IP is coming from.

I've double-checked that I'm editing the correct `php.ini` file, and I've run `grep` on all loaded configuration files to make sure I'm not overriding the value anywhere.

I'm not using the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet anywhere in my local configuration or my docker configuration. I have no idea where the `192.168.0.16` value is coming from. I've run `find / -exec grep "192.168.0" {} \; -print 2>/dev/null` in my container and it comes up with nothing except for xdebug logs indicating that the connection failed.

Any ideas as to how or where my `xdebug.remote_host` setting might be overridden?

Comment: Are you seeing two separate ini files? One for CLI the one for the... SAPI? My guess is the nginx instance is using defaults, in this case `localhost` which resolves to what you see? What does the phpinfo output say regarding "Loaded Configuration File"? Hmm, What is your `remote_connect_back` setting?

Comment: If you have checked all .ini files ... then also check your Docker file for stuff like `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable: you can pass some config that way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took @LazyOne's advice and looked through my `docker-compose.yml` file and found:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_port=9002
```

I am able to modify this setting to change the local values reported from `phpinfo()`. I added my `remote_host` to that variable declaration:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_port=9002 remote_host=10.55.6.26
```

Now I am able to connect to my IDE via a web request.

So it appears that the `php.ini` file is ignored in favor of the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` variable.